# Why does BRepMesh_IncrementalMesh not work?

Tags: c++, openscad

I read a *.stl file through OCC, as follow. I restore TopoDS_Shape from vertices, that TopoDS_Shape will not effected by BRepMesh_IncrementalMesh. So I searched the reason, most said, I should restore topoDS_Shape by B-Spline from vertices. Anybody has ideas?

```
        file = osgDB::convertStringFromCurrentCodePageToUTF8(file);
        //TCollection_AsciiString aName((Standard_CString)file.data());
        BRepBuilderAPI_Sewing shapeSewer{};

        Handle(Poly_Triangulation) aSTLMesh = RWStl::ReadFile(TCollection_AsciiString{ file.c_str() });
        Standard_Integer numberOfTriangles = aSTLMesh->NbTriangles();

        TopoDS_Vertex Vertex1, Vertex2, Vertex3;
        TopoDS_Shape shape{};
        TopoDS_Face face{};
        TopoDS_Wire wire{};


        for (Standard_Integer i = 1; i <= numberOfTriangles; i++)
        {
            Poly_Triangle triangle = aSTLMesh->Triangle(i);

            Standard_Integer n1;
            Standard_Integer n2;
            Standard_Integer n3;

            triangle.Get(n1, n2, n3);

            gp_Pnt p1 = aSTLMesh->Node(n1);
            gp_Pnt p2 = aSTLMesh->Node(n2);
            gp_Pnt p3 = aSTLMesh->Node(n3);

            if (!p1.IsEqual(p2, 0.0) && !p1.IsEqual(p3, 0.0))
            {
                Vertex1 = BRepBuilderAPI_MakeVertex(p1);
                Vertex2 = BRepBuilderAPI_MakeVertex(p2);
                Vertex3 = BRepBuilderAPI_MakeVertex(p3);

                wire = BRepBuilderAPI_MakePolygon(Vertex1, Vertex2, Vertex3, Standard_True);
                if (!wire.IsNull())
                {
                    face = BRepBuilderAPI_MakeFace(wire);
                    if (!face.IsNull()) {
                        shapeSewer.Add(face);

                        //TopoDS_Shell sh{};
                        //BRep_Builder builder;
                        //builder.MakeShell(sh);
                        //builder.Add(sh, face);
                        //builder.Add(shape, sh);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        shapeSewer.Perform();
        shape = shapeSewer.SewedShape();
        BRepBuilderAPI_MakeSolid solidmaker;
        TopTools_IndexedMapOfShape shellMap;
        TopExp::MapShapes(shape, TopAbs_SHELL, shellMap);

        unsigned int counter = 0;
        for (int ishell = 1; ishell <= shellMap.Extent(); ++ishell) {
            const TopoDS_Shell& shell = TopoDS::Shell(shellMap(ishell));
            solidmaker.Add(shell);
            counter++;
        }

        shape = solidmaker.Solid();
```